# Trouble with complex routing rule

Tags: intersystems-ensemble

I have a lookup table called BlockCustomer.  I also have an FTP Adapter that picks up files from multiple customers.  I need to be able to determine the customer from the source of the file and do a lookup on the table.  If BlockCustomer.Customer1 = 0 then it will send it to it's target, otherwise it will do nothing.

If I could use javascript I would do something like this:

`WHEN Lookup(BlockCustomer,HL7.Source.split("/incoming/")[1].split("/")[0]),1) = 0`

But obviously I can't.  I found `$ZSTRIP` but I'm not sure if or how it will work.  Is this possible or am I going to have to create a custom class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cache we use function [$piece](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_fpiece) if needs to get some parts of string by delimiter. For rule you could use the same function called Piece, with the same arguments. So you conditions should looks like:

```
Lookup(BlockCustomer,Piece(HL7.Source,"/incoming/",2),1)=0
```

By the way if you think, that you need some specific functions for you, you can do it by developing it. Just extend the class `Ens.Rule.FunctionSet` and add a method. And function will appear with the same name. As an example you can see at `Ens.Util.FunctionSet` class, which contains almost all available functions.

Comment: Custom function is a great idea. I remember doing that in training now. I could write 'IsBlocked' and simplify the rule a lot.  Thanks for the idea!